# struggling with error involving ridge_models

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am new to R and I have been struggling on this for awhile. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong to get this error?

```
     str(bike)


    bike_recipe=recipe 
  (count~season+mnth+hr+holiday+weekday+workingday+weathersit+temp+atemp+hum+windspeed,bike) 
   %>%

   step_rm (contains("instant", "dteday", "registered", "casual")) %>%

  
     step_dummy(count) %>%

     step_center(all_numeric())  %>%
     step_scale(all_numeric())

    Bike_Ridge_Model=
    linear_reg(mixture =  0)%>%
    set_engine("glmnet")

    ridge_wflow =
    workflow() %>%
    add_model(Bike_Ridge_Model) %>%
    add_recipe(bike_recipe) 

    bike_ridge_fit= fit(ridge_wflow,bike)

   summary(bike_ridge_fit$fit$fit$fit) 

 Error: unused argument ("casual")
```

Comment: Use `dput` and publish `bike` data. Nobody will help you if you show the data in the picture!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).